# chart js data-point between bar charts

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm working of Chart.js library. I wanted to add data-pointer on bar charts. attaching the example image here.. [image]

Tried a lot to implement this. But couldn't get option in chart js. Can anyone please help me out here ?

Comment: Have you tried with data label plugin (see example: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/wo2cd3jf/) or annotation plugin (see example: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/esnjuqzv/)

Comment: @beaver thanks for the links, I'll go through it.. it's much more helpful..

Comment: let me know if those examples help you

Comment: Beaver, thanx a lot bro.. I've implemented with ur reference url's.. It's working as per my requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options with Chart.js:

**1. using [data labels plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels):**

```
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'red',
        align: 'top',
        anchor: 'end',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
            console.log(context)
            if (value>70)
            return "("+context.dataIndex + '): ' + value;
          else
            return "";
        }
      }
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/wo2cd3jf/

**2. using [annotation plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation):**

```
    annotation: {
         drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
         annotations: annotations_array
    }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/esnjuqzv/

Comment: thanks for the code bro. I've written it with annotation plugin. it's working all fine now..

Comment: Generally here on SO you say "thanks" accepting answers and voting them...https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ;-)

Comment: Beaver, can u pls help me here.. label's in annotations is getting cut when it's at right and left side of chart corner. How can I get it front or apply z-index to label in annotations ?

Comment: You can specify min/max values for xAxes to expand range of x axis and so get visibile all annotations labels: check my fiddle updated.

Comment: ya that goes well for smaller text but I've text with 15 to 18 characters how to handle that ?

Comment: I think the only way is to raise the distance from minimum value for xAxes and the first value; check again fiddle updated