# chart js annotation label text is cutting of

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I am using `react-chart js` in my graph I am drawing a multi-vertical line using `annotation` this my sample code i had used to draw line

```
const testValue = ['0.019', '0.033', '0.305', '0.428', '0.582', '0.826'];
    const splitArrayPopup = map(testValue, el => ({
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'vertical',
      scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
      value: parseFloat(el),
      borderColor: '#e0e2e2',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderDash: [3, 3],
      label: {
        content: parseFloat(el),
        position: 'bottom',
        enabled: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        fontColor: '#e0e2e2',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        yPadding: 0,
        yAdjust: -10,
      },
    }));
```

i need to show my label text at bottom of the graph i mean outside the graph, right now for me going inside the graph.

Comment: To avoid labels cutting of, you can try setting min/max for axis. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861122/chart-js-data-point-between-bar-charts/48900184#48900184 and the comments as well

Answer (score 1):

Super late but you can disable clipping on chart bounds allowing your label to be seen outside of the canvas's chart's defined view:

```
plugins: {
  annotation: {
    clip: false,
   }
  annotations: annotations
}
```

Note: the label will still be cut off if the div doesn't have enough space for it. In this case, you need to increase the space the div that contains the chart has.